# How to combine aggregated result and a table in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I need to get the total transaction in the table and our formula involves a count distinct that's why I used derived column and aggregate transformation.

Now that I have the result, I want to add the output of aggregate transformation with another table. I tried union all, but it adds the output in the last entry.

**Example:
Table1**

businessdate,storekey,itemkey,vf,trasnumber

1000,200,200,N,1234

1000,200,123,N,1235

1000,200,124,N,1235

1000,200,200,N,1236

1000,200,200,T,1236

**AggregateTable**

formula: (count distinct transnumber than have vf=n) subtract it with (count distinct transnumber that have vf=t)

**result**

4

I want the combined table to look like this:

**Table2**

businessdate,storekey,itemkey,vf,trasnumber,result

1000,200,200,N,1234,4

1000,200,123,N,1235,4

1000,200,124,N,1235,4

1000,200,200,N,1236,4

1000,200,200,T,1236,4

Would like to ask help on how I can add the result of aggregate transformation at the end of each row in table 1.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a "Dummy Merge Key" e.g. an integer with a fixed value of 1 to both data flow paths (from Table1 and from AggregateTable).

Then you can use a Merge Join transformation to connect the 2 paths (joined on the "Dummy Merge Key", and add the "result" column.

Answer (score 1):

Add an OLE DB Command transformation after the aggregate. This would contain SQL similar to this `update table1 set result = ? where businessdate = ? and storekey = ?` You can then tie the "?" parameters to the output from the Aggregate transformation (I'm assuming here that businessdate and storekey are the keys that you've aggregated on)